# What are my limits and pre req's for my Sql Server 2014 VM?

Tags: sql-server-2014, license, virtualisation

I have the following Virtual SQL Server (running in Windows Server 2016 Hypver-V environment):
The VM is on one specific host shared with other vm's and can be moved around on other hosts.

SQL Version:
***Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2269.0 (X64)
Jun 10 2015 03:35:45
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3  (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)***

My VM has the following specs:
1 virtual Socket
8 Virtual Processors
500 GB SQL DB

[image]

The dev's are breaking my bowling balls as they mention that the app in production is too slow because we are not allocating enough resources VM-wise.

However, I thought that 8 Virtual Procesors is the maximum no?
I found a PDF on the following URL:
https://download.microsoft.com/download/B/4/E/B4E604D9-9D38-4BBA-A927-56E4C872E41C/SQL_Server_2014_Licensing_Guide.pdf

but this looks so psychedelic that I can't even understand half of what's written.

Is there a table somewhere for noob system admins on max specs wise you can give to virtualized SQL Servers?

Comment: As a DEV first, DBA second, I'd personally advise you to push back on the DEVs to provide evidence of why they think it's a hardware resource / contention problem. As David mentioned in his answer, many none-the-wiser DEVs / SysAdmins try to throw hardware to solve what's usually a software problem (e.g. database design and architecture, index architecture and maintenance, etc). If the problem that needs to be solved is *slow queries*, then it's more likely a software problem and should be analyzed with the tools available for performance tuning, such as looking at the **execution plan**.

Comment: As far as who's responsibility it is to be utilizing performance tuning tools, is a grey area that varies depending on the company and teams available at that company. If a DBA or Database Developer is present, then that would likely be under their responsibilities, otherwise generally it would fall under whoever has access to the database and is writing the queries, e.g. the DEVs. So hopefully you can push the onus on them to provide the adequate proof needed (and that proof would make for a good question here). From my personal experience, 8 virtual CPUs should be able to get you a long way.

Answer (score 1):

> I thought that 8 Virtual Procesors is the maximum no?

The document you link to specifically gives an example of more than 8 cores, on page 5, so no 8 is not the limit. But it may depend on how you are currently licensed which you do not state.

Note though that licensing questions are generally considered off-topic here for a couple of reasons, and you should refer to your vendor, so your question is likely to be closed.

> [cpu graph]

A snapshot of current CPU use like that is not particularly meaningful, though at the instant that was taken and the short time before it doesn't look like the CPU cores were being a bottleneck. Further investigation is recommended as just throwing CPU cores at the problem will have no effect if that isn't where your performance issues lie.

Comment: It might be helpful to link to the Edition-specific [hardware limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/2014/getting-started/features-supported-by-the-editions-of-sql-server-2014?view=sql-server-2014&preserve-view=true#CrossBoxScale) for SQL Server 2014.